# Overload Lambda Concurrent

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a use-case with lambda concurrent.

My system uses the API Gateway + Lambda function. I requested AWS for more Limit Concurrent and I get 10000 CCU. But my system is going to solve about 30000 concurrent users.

First, I tried using lambda async by this guide [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html]
[image]

But my application use REST API and the result get 500 code of the response. The document said

> "In this case, the backend Lambda function is invoked asynchronously,
> and the front-end REST API method doesn't return the result"

Then, I search for one more solution that use Lambda Async. It used lambda async invoke from another sync Lambda. But this way didn't use for API GET of some methods that required validation.

Now, we go back with the solution that uses the provision concurrent, but this solution may not be useful. I am concerned about the concurrent that not enough.

Please, help me. Sorry about my English skill

Comment: Do you ***really*** have 30000 users that have running web request at the same time?? 30k logged in users do not matter, the question is if you actually would have 30k concurrent requests. At that point ECS / Fargate may be a better idea.

Comment: but the system must be use lambda. can you have any idea?